# Help needed with a problem

Tags: problems, retrograde-analysis

On an empty board, how can you place a White king, two White, rooks, and a Black king so that White can give mate in 4 ways from that position?

Answer (score 4):

```
[FEN "8/8/8/8/8/8/2R5/k3K2R w K - 0 1"]
```

From this position, Kd2 Ke2 Kf2 and O-O deliver checkmate

Comment: It is possible. But i can't figure it out. We need to think outside the box i think. I managed to do a situation where i can get 3 mates but from there i'm lost. Imagine this: black king on b8, white rooks an d7 and h8. White king on f8. So white can give mate in 3 ways with discovered check as the white king can go to e7,f7 or g7. And i think this is the catch. Not only rook moves deliver mate but olso king with discovered check. But i can't find a situation where you can give mate in 4 ways. What do you think about my idea?

Comment: Yes, now I understand and I have it. Will deliver.

Comment: Of course. Forgot obout 0-0 :) see... it can be done. Wow... that's a neat puzzle